# What are the equivalent classes for ContractClass and ContractClassFor in .Net standard Library 1.2

Tags: xamarin, cross-platform, .net-standard

I am converting my .Net 4.5 class library to .Net Standard Library 1.2 (as we want to support Cross platform.

Few of my classes and interfaces use attributes ContractClassFor and ContractClass. These classes belongs to System.Diagnostics.Contracts. But I can not find thess classes in XAMARIN. 
What are the equivalent classes for those I can use? Or if no classes present, how can I replace the code with ?

Thanks so much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using .NETStandard, you need to use NuGet packages for any missing namespaces. In your case you would need to install the [System.Diagnostics.Contracts](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Diagnostics.Contracts/) NuGet to unlock the desired functionality.

As the NuGet description says, it provides the ContractClass and ContractClassFor attributes you are missing.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. You were partially right. We need to use\mention it explicitly(specify System.Diagnostics.Contracts to use those classes). The only slight modification in the answer is, we only need to install NuGet package in Portable Class Library (PCL). But when we use .Net Standard Library, we just need to update Project.Json file with "System.Diagnostics.Contracts": "4.3.0" line. thats the benefit of .Net Standard Library over PCL.

Comment: Modifying the project.json file to depend on System.Diagnostics.Contracts is essentially the same as installing a NuGet package.